# Node.js- How to send a varaible from route's js file to layout.jade

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I am working on node.js and express. Using jade as my template engine. I am displaying a navbar which is static.I kept it in layout.jade. I have a login form and need to display user name on the navbar.I am using session to store username and using **req.app.locals.env=req.session.username;**.
 Now username is global and can use in layout. Its working. But the problem is when I open two users in different browsers, only recently logged in username is displayed for all remaining users in navbars. Can any one help me?

here are the screenshots of my output.

[a user logged in chrome(suresh)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfzQx.png)

[another user logged in firefox(user)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AoAM.png)

Navbar in my output is in layout.jade which i extended in all views.I opened two users in different browsers.
The problem is when I click view,insert, home r any button in navbar,the name "suresh" is changed to "user" in navbar.Since I am displaying name as gobal and storing the session value to dislpay the name in layout.jade. Is there any Other way to display username in Layout?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are saving username in session and session gets updated after recent login. 
Best way to do this is send usersInfo to route on render.

```
 res.render('/home', { userInfo: userInfo });
```

Comment: can we render a layout.jade? Its a static one which is displayed for all jade templates

Comment: You can render it but you don't have to just keep it as a basic layout for all pages and then extend it in all other views (e.g. home, about, contact) using Jade's (extends layout.pug) feature.

Comment: I edited my question and added output.Please have a look